# Should i Bind variables all the time?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When a User `Login` to the Website

```
    users
[id  -  name]
[1   -  mark]
[2   -  jean]
[3   -  mary]
```

I pull from the previous table the `id` and `name` using the following query:

`$Query = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE ~";`

Then i Check the pulled Data:

```
if (ctype_digit($row['id'])) {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
        //Pretened that i didn't use AUTO_INCREMENT in the Table.
} else {
  logout();
}
```

---

Now for **example** i want to pull the name from the **Database** using the `$id = $_SESSION['id']`

Should I bind the `$id`

```
$Query = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = :id";
    //...execute(['id' => $id])
```

or Just add the `$id` directly

```
$Query = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = $id";
    //...execute();
```

---

Should i only bind `Input`s values from `$_POST/GET['value'];` Only

Or even `$_SESSION['INT/STR'];` checked and cleaned by PHP `preg_replace()` `ctype_digit/alnum()` functions?

Comment: It's better to be consistent and bind them at all times. You might want to change the source at some point, and if you do, you're already set. And even if you get the values from some "safe" place, they can still contain some bad characters like `'` or end with a back slash which would break your query if you concatenate it.

Comment: Yes, it's better to do so. You never know when you gonna store an unsafe value in your session ;)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Wouldn't cleaning the `$_SESSION` variables from bad characters before defining them be Faster and Easier?

Comment: You should never trust _any_ input. If a first time you use prepared statements, but later on not, you'll be vulnerable to **second order sql injection**.

Comment: Why do that manually when prepared statements does it for you and even does it better? Even `mysqli_real_escape_string()` has some security issues in certain situations.

Comment: Regarding the speed, I don't have any facts, but imo, it should be faster since you prepare once, and then you can bind and run it multiple times.

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal If all the time `$_SESSION` values is made from `Alphanumeric Letters` Doesn't binding them be an overkill for it?

Comment: Don't micro optimize your code before you _really_ need to.  I doubt that any theoretical overhead would affect anything in your script. Focus on security instead.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson So if i have `$_SESSION['var']` I have two ways to go, 1. using PHP manually to check it `if (ctype_alnum($var))` then using `#1` query, Or 2. using PDO binding without my PHP steps. So the problem is, Which is faster, PDO Binding or PHP Checking.

Comment: Yes. If you're using prepared statements and bind your params, then you don't need to check the type (for any other reason than validation) or clean/escape it at all. Just pass it. So at the end of the day, that will most likely even be easier.

Comment: Well. Toleo, I'm solely stating my opinion. Consider having to run your query multiple times, it will surely be much faster to bind and run.

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal But what about the assured `SESSION` varibles like `id` it is always an `INT`, Why is the need to bind it If it came directly from the database as `INT`?

Comment: Usually you create reusable methods like `getUserContacts($userId)` where you pass the ID. Then you can reuse that function for any user in any situation (like getting friends contacts or what not). Using `$_SESSION` directly with your query is a bad practice to start with since it won't be as testable nor reusable.

Comment: @Toleo you need to be consistent. As someone earlier stated, not being consistent  will leave you with vulnerabilities at some point.

Comment: This comes into play more for 'updating old code' than 'making new code'. As making new code you should just be preparing everything feasible, and never worry about it. As for old code, going through possibly hundreds of thousands of querys and rebuilding them all to be prepared when some are clearly not needed (using an int ID from an already grabbed int database field for example), then becomes a time-manager task to dictate what should or should not be converted given the project scope and deadlines. (* key point managers never have a clue how to code, so sometimes we are at their mercy)

Comment: @IncredibleHat Understood, Updated the question look and style to be more answerable.

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal I understood that it is better to bind it to be future-proof, But for `ID`s and `Numerics`, What is the point to bind them if they're always and always going to be an `INT`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The performance difference is negligible. In [some tests](https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/08/02/mysql-prepared-statements/) it even appears that `prepare()` & `execute()` is slightly *faster*.

There may be some edge cases in SQL where the use of parameters can give the optimizer the wrong idea about the query, and it might not use an index that it should. But these cases are rare. Deal with them when and if you ever encounter them.

There might be cases where's it's 100% guaranteed that a variable is safe, and it's easier for your code readability and maintenance to avoid using a parameter.

But performance should not be the reason. Favor security over performance.

If you ever get hacked, you'll wish you did.

---

P.S.: I suggest that if micro-optimized performance were really important to you, then you should use a language like Java or Go, not a scripting language like PHP.

Comment: I don't backup the first good reason from that linked article . "So there are good reasons to use prepared statements: 1) Save on query parsing " Sounds like nonsense.. Queries always will be parsed and optimized even if you run a PREPARE command.

Comment: I think that would make `execute(['id' => $id])` faster than `if (ctype_digit($id))`

Comment: @RaymondNijland, Yes, a query is parsed during prepare(), but after a query is prepared, it can be re-executed many times. The SQL parsing doesn't happen on execute(). If you've got a loop where you run the same query over and over with different parameters, you can prepare() once before the loop, and execute() inside the loop without re-parsing.